# How to convert this number 1.2886343E7 to Kilometers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I try to calculate distance between 2 location with distance between, so i get this result 1.2886343E7. How can i convert it to Kilometers?

```
Location.distanceBetween(Double.parseDouble(lat1.getText().toString()), Double.parseDouble(lng1.getText().toString()),Double.parseDouble(lat2.getText().toString()),Double.parseDouble(lng2.getText().toString()), result);
```

Comment: And what is the unit of the value, is it millimeters, centimeters, meters, kilometers, miles, feet, inches, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `Location.distanceBetween()` returns the distance in meters. `E7` means `* 10^7`. Divide the result by 1000 and you will get the distance in kilometers.

Comment: That isnt real distance

Comment: What do you mean with real distance? Dividing the function's result by 1000 returns the distance in kilometers.